# Saving loop iterations as new column in Python

Tags: python, numpy

very new to Python (and coding in general) and I'm trying to save each loop iteration to a new column. Specifically, there are 3 loops (basisAges is 1×3) and each loop produces 'y', a 1×83 row array.  I want to create a 83×3 matrix called 'Phi' which saves each iteration of y to a new column in Phi.  Some help would be very much appreciated.

P.S. this is a bit code copied over from matlab so there it is just:

```matlab
Phi(:,i) = y;
```

Hopefully, someone can shed a bit of light on this for me!

```
basisAges = config.basisAges

for i in np.arange(0, len(basisAges[0])):
    basisAge = basisAges[:, i]
    if i != 0:
        ageBefore = basisAges[:, i-1]
    else:
        ageBefore = basisAge - 1

    if i != len(basisAges[0]) - 1:
        ageAfter = basisAges[:, i+1]
    else:
        ageAfter = basisAge + 1

    y1 = 1.0 / (basisAge - ageBefore) * (age - ageBefore)
    y2 = 1 - 1.0 / (ageAfter - basisAge) * (age - basisAge)
    y = np.multiply(np.logical_and(age >= ageBefore, age <= basisAge), y1) + np.multiply(np.logical_and(age > basisAge, age <= ageAfter), y2)
```

Comment: It's more or less the same in Python, except you have to preallocate Phi: `Phi=np.empty((83,3), dtype=<your_dtype>)` and then in the loop `Phi[:, i] = y`, if y is (83,). If `y` is (1,83) you have to `squeeze` or `ravel` it or pick `y[0]`.

Comment: Thanks, got it working now.